# Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 78

Tags: sql, subquery

I am getting this error from the code below:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 78

```
select CustomerName, OrderDate
from [Sales].Customers
join Sales.Orders
on Sales.Orders.CustomerID = Sales.Customers.CustomerID
where OrderDate = (select OrderDate
                   from Sales.Orders
                   where Month(OrderDate) = 01
                   and DATEPART(DAY, OrderDate) = 10)
```

How do I resolve this?

I need customer names where order dates are from 10th of January.

Comment: That only works if the inner SELECT returns one record, and in that case there's no point in using the inner select at all.  Just use the WHERE clauses with the outer SELECT.

Comment: `IN` subquery is the quickest solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't this the same as:

```
SELECT Sales.Customers.CustomerName, Sales.Orders.OrderDate
FROM Sales.Customers JOIN Sales.Orders ON 
     Sales.Orders.CustomerID=Sales.Customers.CustomerID 
WHERE Month(Sales.Orders.OrderDate)= 01
  AND DATEPART(DAY, Sales.Orders.OrderDate) = 10);
```